# Unity Vimeo SDK - problem with CORS and WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to load a video from Vimeo into player, but I am running into CORS problems when building to WebGL.

That's the error:

> "Access to video at 'https‍://vimeo-...' from origin 'http‍://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

*works fine before build...

Unity version: 2019.1.6f1

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I quote from the link "Enabling CORS lets the server tell the browser it's permitted to use an additional origin"
So would you agree this is a problem with Vimeo's server CORS configuration policy, and would be out of our control?

Answer (score 0):

I chased Vimeo support.

Part of my message to them:

> This appears to be a problem on Vimeo's side in relation to the
> server's CORS policy. [I may be wrong but] it would be out of control
> of the Vimeo-Unity-SDK client.
>
> There are plenty of unclosed issues in the Vimeo-Unity-SDK relating to
> the issue I am facing:
> https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues?q=CORS

And this is Vimeo's official response:

> Taylor T. (Vimeo Support) Aug 4, 2020, 5:36 PM EDT
>
> Hi, Understood. We're aware of this issue, however we cannot
> provide any ETA for a potential fix or any changes. Our apologies for
> any inconvenience this causes you!
>
> Sincerely, Taylor T. Specialist, Vimeo Developer API + Apps